# Search criteria dropdown choices disappeared

Tags: search-builder

I am using Search Builder to make custom searches. I want to search on a Membership field "Payment Method". After entering the operator = normally a small box appeared with a drop-down of the various options (cash, cheque, Direct Debit, etc.) from which I selected the desired option. This has worked fine for me in the past, however yesterday in my haste I accidentally entered a number in the window before selecting the option. Now I can't get the options back. All that comes up is the erroneous number and several other things I have tried.

How do I get my options back?  Seems like a cache issue, but I haven't a clue what to clear. I've tried different browsers on my local machine, but it must be something in CiviCRM.

CiviCRM 4.6.24, Drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

This may have been a non-problem. Our developer noted that the particular variable I am concerned about is a custom variable, and it seems that custom variables do not present drop-down menus as do the standard variables. One then has to construct the search using the values defined for the custom variables (which would have to be looked up elsewhere in CiviCRM).